# Insert horizontal line separator in between rows of Datatable in JSF 2.0

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, datatable

How to Insert horizontal line separator in between the rows of h:datatable in JSF 2.0

Comment: Aren't table cells the 'natural separators' of `<table>`? What do you mean?

Comment: I want a visible horizontal line after each row of the data table..

Comment: You should draw an image to illustrate what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **rules** attribute of **`<h:datatable>`** tag.

The rules attribute specifies which lines will appear between cells in the table. The valid values for this attribute are:

- none (no rules, default value)
- groups (between row groups)
- rows (between rows only)
- cols (between columns only)
- all (between all rows and columns)